# How did the EMH remain "solid" when beamed aboard the hologram ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh, hologram

In "Flesh and Blood," the holograms beam the EMH over to their ship. Just prior to doing so, Tom Paris attempts to download the EMH's program into the mobile emitter. I assume this would keep the EMH "grounded" on Voyager, since he could simply be "booted" up in sickbay using the mobile emitter. I think that for the hologram ship to claim the EMH, the holograms would then have to beam over the mobile emitter, and presumably this is not easy.

However, when the EMH is beamed over, how can he remain intact? Essentially the EMH is nothing but light and forcefields, and if his program is still in Voyager's main computer, how could he be "grounded" on the hologram ship?

Unless, perhaps, the EMH program in Voyager's computers was powering the EMH from a distance. Though when the hologram ship went out of range, the EMH wouldn't be able to remain "intact" any longer.

Comment: In VOY *Future's End* it is shown to be possible to use a transporter beam to download data from Voyager's computer. The likely explanation is that they moved the Doctor's program during the beam out before Paris could download it to the mobile emitter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## They didn't beam him over.  They transferred his program.

I think the misunderstanding here has to do with the belief that he was beamed over.  This wasn't the case:

> **KIM:** The holograms are tapping into the Sickbay emitters. They're trying to transfer the Doctor's program off the ship!

What they accomplished was more akin to hacking into Voyager's computer rather than beaming over the Doctor.

It was logical to try to transfer the Doctor into the mobile emitter, to prevent the holograms from accessing his program through the computer, but Tom threw the emitter to the Doctor about one second too late.